# Remove metadata properties from JSON ADF

Tags: json, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, parquet

I have json file in ADLS and wanted  to remove metadata properties from json file and convert it to parquet using ADF pipelines or using pyspark dataframe. An example of this data is the following

```
[
  {
    "metadata": {
      "pageNumber": 1,
      "totalPages": 3,
      "recordCount": 1000,
      "totalRecords": 2097
    },
    "records": [
      {
        "doctor_id": "3678356",
        "doctor_name": "AAasIasM asdas",
        "center_id": "2",
        "speciality": "Homeopathy",
        "degree": null,
        "is_active": "Yes",
        "license_no": "DH1A-P-0asda17",
        "usertype": "EXTERNAL USER",
        "total_count": "2097"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please tell us about the destination where you want these records to be pushed

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove **metadata** from a JSON file using ADF, you can use the **Dataflow activity** in ADF. Below are the steps to do so:

1. Take the source transformation with the JSON file as a dataset. In JSON settings, choose `Array of documents` as the document form.

[image]

2. Then, take the **Flatten transformation** and unroll the **records** array. Add rule-based mapping by clicking on `+ Add Mapping` and provide the mapping as in the image below.

[image]

The output of the flatten transformation will be similar to the image below.

[image]

3. Take the sink transformation with the Parquet file as the dataset. You can output the data to a single file by choosing that option in the file name option and selecting `set single partition` in the optimize tab.

[image]